# PHP jpgraph won't display multiple graphs

Tags: php, jpgraph

I've been trying to display two graphs on the one screen using jpgraph php code. According to jpgraph this can be completed by following one of two methods see [here](http://jpgraph.net/doc/howto1.php). While I can get any one of the four graphs to appear individually using $graph->Stroke(); I can't for the life of me work out how to display them together using either of the methods prescribed in the jpgraph example. The code for mgraph in the attached document looks correct to me but nothing will appear. Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

```
    <?php require("sess_start.php");?><?php if ($_GET[sessid] > 0) { //show page if user has a valid session ?><?php
//    AppServerType:PHP4

require("./../adodb/adodb.inc.php");
require("./../Connections/m_water.php");


include ("./../jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php");
include ("./../jpgraph/src/jpgraph_line.php");

$ydata = array(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32);
$datax = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
$max_inshore_effort = array("8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8",     "8", "8", "8", "8", "8");
$max_offshore_effort = array("12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12");


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//GRAPH 1

// Create the graph. These two calls are always required
//$graph = new Graph(550,400,"auto");
//$graph->SetScale("textlin");

//$graph->xaxis-> SetTickLabels($datax);
//$graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_FONT2);
//$graph->yaxis->SetFont(FF_FONT2);


// Create the linear plot
//$lineplot=new LinePlot($ydata);


  // Add the plot to the graph
  //$graph->Add($lineplot);
  //$lineplot->SetColor('#DC143C');  //set the colour of the line this case dark red
 //$lineplot->SetWeight(1.5); // set the thickness of the line
 //$lineplot->SetLegend('Total group effort'); // add a description to the legend
//$lineplot->mark->SetType(MARK_FILLEDCIRCLE,'',1.0); // determine what type of marker is used
 //$lineplot->mark->SetType(MARK_SQUARE,'',2.0); // determine what type of marker is used
 //$lineplot->mark->SetSize(6);
//$lineplot->mark->SetColor('#000000');   // determine the colour of the outer line surrounding the marker
//$lineplot->mark->SetFillColor('#DC143C'); // set the fill for the marker


//$graph->img->SetMargin(60,60,50,80);
//$graph->xaxis->SetTitle('Round', 'center');
//$graph->yaxis->SetTitle('Total group effort', 'center');
 //$graph->xaxis->SetTitleMargin(12);
 //$graph->yaxis->SetTitleMargin(32);

// Setup a nice title with a striped bevel background
//$graph->title->Set("State of Area 1 (Inshore)"); // alter the title heading
//$graph->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,16); // alter the font of the title and size
   //$graph->title->SetColor('#FFFFFF');   // alter the colour of the title
    //$graph->SetTitleBackground('#4682B4',TITLEBKG_STYLE1,TITLEBKG_FRAME_BEVEL); // insert 3d bevel for title
             //$graph->SetTitleBackgroundFillStyle(TITLEBKG_FILLSTYLE_HSTRIPED,'blue','darkgreen');  // insert alternating horizontal lines across title fill box;


 //$graph->tabtitle->SetColor('navy','lightyellow','navy');

 //$graph->yaxis->SetColor('#000000'); //set the colour of the y axis
 //$graph->xaxis->SetColor('#000000'); // set the colour of the x axis

  // Change the fonts of the axis and title
  //$graph->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);
  //$graph->yaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);
 //$graph->xaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);
//$graph->xaxis->SetTickSide(SIDE_DOWN);
 //$graph->xaxis->SetLabelMargin(6);
//$graph->yaxis->SetTickSide(SIDE_LEFT);
 //$graph->yaxis->SetLabelMargin(8);

  //$lineplot->SetColor("#DC143C");

 // Add a second axis displaying the maximum effort allowed for inshore area
 //$p1 = new LinePlot($max_inshore_effort);
 //$graph->Add($p1);
 //$p1->SetColor("#2E8B57");
//$p1->SetLegend('Max effort inshore to stay abundant');
//$p1->SetWeight(3); // set the thickness of the line
 //$p1->SetCenter();
//$p1->SetStyle('longdashed');

 //$graph->SetShadow();

   // Adjust the legend position
  //$graph->legend->SetLayout(LEGEND_HOR);
 //$graph->legend->Pos(0.15,0.94,"bottom","center");  //adjust the position of the    legend on the graph
   //$graph->legend->SetFillColor('#D3D3D3');

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//GRAPH 2

   // Create the graph. These two calls are always required
$graph2 = new Graph(550,400,"auto");
$graph2->SetScale("textlin");

$graph2->xaxis-> SetTickLabels($datax);
 $graph2->xaxis->SetFont(FF_FONT2);
$graph2->yaxis->SetFont(FF_FONT2);


// Create the linear plot
 $lineplot2=new LinePlot($ydata);


    // Add the plot to the graph
   $graph2->Add($lineplot2);
   $lineplot2->SetColor('#DC143C');  //set the colour of the line this case dark red
    $lineplot2->SetWeight(1.5); // set the thickness of the line
  $lineplot2->SetLegend('Total group effort'); // add a description to the legend
   //$lineplot->mark->SetType(MARK_FILLEDCIRCLE,'',1.0); // determine what type of marker is used
    $lineplot2->mark->SetType(MARK_SQUARE,'',2.0); // determine what type of marker is used
    $lineplot2->mark->SetSize(6);
   $lineplot2->mark->SetColor('#000000');   // determine the colour of the outer line surrounding the marker
    $lineplot2->mark->SetFillColor('#DC143C'); // set the fill for the marker


 $graph2->img->SetMargin(60,60,50,80);
 $graph2->xaxis->SetTitle('Round', 'center');
$graph2->yaxis->SetTitle('Total group effort', 'center');
$graph2->xaxis->SetTitleMargin(12);
$graph2->yaxis->SetTitleMargin(32);

 // Setup a nice title with a striped bevel background
    $graph2->title->Set("State of Area 1 (Offshore)"); // alter the title heading
    $graph2->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,16); // alter the font of the title and size
    $graph2->title->SetColor('#FFFFFF');   // alter the colour of the title
    $graph2->SetTitleBackground('#4682B4',TITLEBKG_STYLE1,TITLEBKG_FRAME_BEVEL); // insert 3d bevel for title
 //$graph->SetTitleBackgroundFillStyle(TITLEBKG_FILLSTYLE_HSTRIPED,'blue','darkgreen');     //      insert alternating horizontal lines across title fill box;


$graph2->tabtitle->SetColor('navy','lightyellow','navy');

  $graph2->yaxis->SetColor('#000000'); //set the colour of the y axis
 $graph2->xaxis->SetColor('#000000'); // set the colour of the x axis

 // Change the fonts of the axis and title
 $graph2->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);
 $graph2->yaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);
$graph2->xaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);
$graph2->xaxis->SetTickSide(SIDE_DOWN);
$graph2->xaxis->SetLabelMargin(6);
 $graph2->yaxis->SetTickSide(SIDE_LEFT);
 $graph2->yaxis->SetLabelMargin(8);

 $lineplot2->SetColor("#DC143C");

// Add a second axis displaying the maximum effort allowed for inshore area
$p12 = new LinePlot($max_offshore_effort);
$graph2->Add($p12);
$p12->SetColor("#0000CD");
$p12->SetLegend('Max effort offshore to stay abundant');
$p12->SetWeight(3); // set the thickness of the line
$p12->SetCenter();
$p12->SetStyle('longdashed');

 $graph2->SetShadow();

 // Adjust the legend position
 $graph2->legend->SetLayout(LEGEND_HOR);
$graph2->legend->Pos(0.15,0.94,"bottom","center");  //adjust the position of the legend on the graph
$graph2->legend->SetFillColor('#D3D3D3');
 //$handle2 =  $graph2->Stroke( _IMG_HANDLER);

// Display the individual graph
$graph->Stroke();
?>
?>

// Create a combined graph
       //$mgraph = new MGraph();
     //$xpos1=3;$ypos1=3;
      //$xpos2=3;$ypos2=200;
      //$mgraph->Add($graph);
     //$mgraph->Add($graph2,$xpos2,$ypos2);
    //$mgraph->Stroke();

?>
   <?php } //show page if user has a valid session ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, your are using `$graph->Stroke();` but your variable name is `$graph2`. 
I don't know if this is the reason of your problem but in this case `$graph->Stroke();` will output nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand `graph->Stroke()` is going to give output as image file and multiple instances of `graph->Stroke;` `graph2->Stroke;` etc will override previous ones displaying only final image.
What I would suggest doing, is, make a file something like
**plotgraph.php:**

```
<?php

$xdata=explode(",",$_GET['xdata']);
$ydata=explode(",",$_GET['ydata']);
$title=$_GET['graphtitle'];
// and any other variales that you need
// Your graph routines
// .. including $p->add($xdata,$ydata); etc statements
$graph->Stroke();
?>
```

In your main file add statement like

```
<img src="plotgraph.php?xdata=comma_separated_xdata&ydata=comma_separated_ydata&graphtitle=your_graph_title">
```

That way, you can insert as many graphs as you want with various parameters. I hope that clariefies things a bit. 
(Note that you I haven't added all the graph formatting etc, just giving you example. If you want separate font etc formatting for each graph, you'll have to export that with url and fetch with $_GET. Other common settings can bbe in your plotgraph.php file)